# Random custom view selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a view controller which includes a scrollview and on scrollview i am adding 5 different custom UIView horizontally and i want that custom UIView should be added randomly depending on custom UIViews width and accordingly contentSize of scrollView should be set.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I assumed that you have five different size UIViews and you want to add one of those five UIViews to the scrollview depending upon the current size of the scrollview.  Is this correct?

Comment: I want to add all 5 different UIViews into scrollViews but randomly depending on their size and after adding contentSize should be change of scrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i came up with solution

Just put your five view in a mutable array, and initialize your x offset to 0. Then get a random number and grab the view in the array (random modulo array count, to stay inside the array). Add this view to your scrollview and increase your x offset by the width of the choosed view. Stop when array count is zero for example. Then your x tells you the width of your scrollview, simply set its contentSize :

```
theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( x, theScrollView.frame.size.height);
```