# Random selection of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random custom view selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572291/random-custom-view-selector)

I have created a view controller which includes a single scrollview

```
scrollView = [UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
```

and on the scrollview i have to add 5 different custom UIView horizontally

```
 FirstView *firstView = [FirstView alloc] init]; //width = 100
 SecondView *secondView = [SecondView alloc] init]; //width = 150
 ThirdView *thirdView = [ThirdView alloc] init]; //width = 175
 FourthView *fourthView = [FourthView alloc] init]; //width = 200
 FifthView *fifthView = [FifthView alloc] init]; //width = 250
```

and i want that custom UIView should be added randomly depending on custom UIViews width and accordingly contentSize of scrollView should be set.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: ya but i did not find the solution for that hence i made it more simple way

Comment: ya i am wrong here sorry for this

Comment: You can just take what you've added here and edit the original question to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your five view in a mutable array, and initialize your x offset to 0.
Then get a random number and grab the view in the array (random modulo array count, to stay inside the array). Add this view to your scrollview and increase your x offset by the width of the choosed view. Stop when array count is zero for example.
Then your x tells you the width of your scrollview, simply set its contentSize :

```
theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( x, theScrollView.frame.size.height);
```